# What are the php.ini parameters to set for sending email?

Tags: wamp, php

I want to send email from my PHP code, but I received warning messages. So what are the php.ini parameters to set ?

Comment: What do the warning messages say?

Comment: Go through http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: the warning is : `[14-Mar-2013 09:52:42] PHP Warning:  mail() [<a href='function.mail'>function.mail</a>]: Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\MP_Local\lib\mail.lib.php on line 99`

Comment: Is the SMTP server even running on `localhost` and port `25`

Comment: seems your mail function is not succesfully configured...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To check/change your PHP mail configuration:

Open your php.ini file (if you don't know where this is, see below)
Search for the line that reads [mail function]
Add/change the details of your mail server. This could be a local mail server or the mail server of your ISP.
Save/close the php.ini file
Restart your web server

An example of what the mail settings could look like when you first open the php.ini file:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
;sendmail_path =
```

Additional info is in echoing `phpinfo()` you can view your PHP configuration details. You can do this by creating a .php file with the following line on it: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. When you run this in your browser, you will see a full list of PHP configuration variables. Simply search for the lines that contain php.ini and `sendmail_path` to see the values you need to use.

Another idea is you might use `ini_set()` to properly config your mail setting like this

Add the following code to the top of your email script if your mail script continues to fail.

```
// Please specify your Mail Server - Example: mail.example.com.
ini_set("SMTP","mail.example.com");

// Please specify an SMTP Number 25 and 8889 are valid SMTP Ports.
ini_set("smtp_port","25");

// Please specify the return address to use
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'example@YourDomain.com');
```

Comment: Well actually this issue is that WINDOWS does not come with a mail server. You have to install one to make send() work as well as change some config parameters.