# how do I get and use php.ini for sending email

Tags: php, javascript

I was trying to sending email by mail() in php. The following is the code I'm using.
But W3School suggest tsing php.ini

They say:
"Requirements
For the mail functions to be available, PHP requires an installed and working email system. The program to be used is defined by the configuration settings in the php.ini file."

But I have no idea how to find this php.ini and how to use it. Any suggestions? Thanks

```
<html>
<head>


<?php

echo 'hello';
 $to = "aaa@gmail.com";
 $subject = "Test mail";
 $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
 $from = "someonelse@example.com";
 $headers = "From:" . $from;
 mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
 echo "Mail Sent.";
 ?>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Mail page</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the php.ini parameters to set for sending email?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402887/what-are-the-php-ini-parameters-to-set-for-sending-email)

Answer (score 2):

The `php.ini` file is stored in your webserver configuration. The location of that depends on your OS. On linux, it'll be `/etc/php/php.ini` or `/etc/php.ini`. On windows with WAMP or XAMPP, you can open it using the toolbar icon for the server.

What W3School suggests is that you make sure that mail is enabled in your `php.ini` file. `php.ini` is the configuration file for PHP. If mail is not properly configured in it, then it won't work.

Be warned that many web hosts have PHP mail disabled because it is incredibly easy to automate spam using it. Fewer hosts do that now that spam filters have gotten much better, but it still does happen (especially on free hosts).

Answer (score 0):

`php.ini` is very useful and it is a configuration file that is used to customize behavior of PHP at runtime.

> PHP requires an installed and working email system. The program to be used is defined by the configuration settings in the php.ini file.

This means you have to install some sort of mailserver and configure php to use it. Usually this mailserver is postfix in Ubuntu. However - if the php side you are coding will eventually be stored on a hosting service's side (e.g. xmission), a mail server will most likely already be installed there. In that case just test your site online instead of localy.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can search for [mail function] inside php.ini file, however, if you are using Apache on your local server, you can't send email using php mail() function, because sending email requires SMTP server at that case (Public IP Address) to talk with remote host that you send the email, generally, people don't send email from local server, and if so, you need to send email using SMTP method, another option is to install SMTP server on your local pc but this is not recommended.

you can look at http://swiftmailer.org/ and try to read more about it.