# Mail function and smtp does not working on window server 2008

Tags: php, email, smtp, windows-server-2008, phpmailer

I'm trying to send email via `mail()` function and smtp but it does not work on windows server 2008, I checked same process and code on bluehost server which is working fine.

### Mail Function Error

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: Alen <example1@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: john Smith <example2@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
$message = "
<strong>Hi xyz,  </strong><br />
<p>Your new password is asd,  </p>
";
echo mail('example1@gmail.com', 'Need to CHeck', $message, $headers);
```

I tried above email function which is giving me following error in error log.

> PHP Warning:  mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at
>   "mail.reliedhosting.com" port 25, verify your
>   "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use
>   ini_set() in

I tried this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402887/what-are-the-php-ini-parameters-to-set-for-sending-email)** for resolving my issue but did not resolved.

### SMTP Does not Connect

I also tried to connect smtp but it does not connecting.

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
        $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
        $mail->Host = "mail.exampleDomain.com";
        $mail->Port = 25;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = "info@cms.exampleDomain.ae";
        $mail->Password = "myPassWord";
        $mail->setFrom('info@cms.exampleDomain.ae', 'John');
        $mail->addReplyTo('web@example.com', 'Jimm');
        $mail->addAddress($email, $name);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->msgHTML('<h1>'.$message.'</h1>');
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo "Message sent!";
        }
```

Code is returning following error

> SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: The requested address is not
>   valid in its context. (10049) SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Mailer
>   Error: SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/TroubleshootingFunction
>   Executed

I have searched for that, according to my research i thought that may be smtp cofiguration is not correct, but when i checked through `phpinfo()` it showing correct according to this **[reference](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp)**.

I'm also attaching a part of phpinfo page, kindly view it. Can any one guide me where is the issue and how can i fix it I would like to highly appreciate. 
[image]

Comment: This is covered in the troubleshooting docs linked from the error; Your mail server (`mail.reliedhosting.com`) is not responding.

Comment: Because you included it in your question?

Comment: @Synchro so what should i do for resolving my problem

Comment: Fix your mail server, or use one that works.

Comment: @Synchro I checked, but i have limited privileges in control panel, so how can i fix can you kindly guide me.

Comment: Sorry, you'll need to ask your hosting provider.

Comment: @Synchro Sure, So I will tell them that `mail server does not responding kindly fit the issue`. Am I right ?

Comment: Ask them to confirm the mail server details you need for sending email and use the settings they tell you. They probably have documentation on this already, so check that first. It looks likely that you have the wrong host name, possibly the wrong port number too.

Comment: @Synchro I checked port its 25, and they me host name, but i'm not sure its correct  or not. Also our code on sub-domain. Thanks You

Comment: Well that host name is not in DNS, so that's clearly wrong. Port 25 is usually only used for inbound SMTP, not outbound - I'd expect you to be using port 587 - see the PHPMailer docs.

Comment: @Synchro yes you are saying right, actually my client give me access on sub domain `cms.example.com` and also he send me two url for mail.ONE `mail.reliedhosting.com` and SECOND `mail.cms.example.com`. But these does not working

Comment: @Synchro Thank you so much for your guideline and time